# How to visit all folders and run a function?

Tags: string, python-3.x, while-loop, directory

I am relatively new to Python. 
I am trying to create a program that delete 3 strings from reverse if '_L2' exists in filename.
This is the code.

```
import os


def deleteInCurrent():
    L = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    for i in range(len(L)):
        filename = L[i].rsplit(".", 1)[0]
        if '_L2' in filename:
            os.rename(filename+'.'+L[i].rsplit(".", 1)[1], filename[0:len(filename)-3]+'.'+L[i].rsplit(".", 1)[1])

print(os.getcwd())
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    deleteInCurrent()
    for i in range(len(dirs)):
        os.chdir(dirs[i])
        deleteInCurrent()
        os.chdir("..")
print("Done")
```

Here, I was able to delete the current directory and the files at lower directories.

What I could do was inspecting the current and 1 depth lower directory, delete 3 strings from reverse if '_L2' exists.

But what I want to do is inspecting all files in all folders and do the same thing automatically.

Can I get a piece of advice?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you use the "pathlib" module instead of the "os" module?

If so, the following code should do what you want:

```
from pathlib import Path

def ren(old_pathlib_path):
    parent = old_pathlib_path.parent
    stem = old_pathlib_path.stem
    suffix = old_pathlib_path.suffix
    if '_L2' in stem:
        stem = stem[:-3]
        new_pathlib_path = parent / (stem + suffix)
        old_pathlib_path.rename(new_pathlib_path)

start = Path('abs_topmost_dir_path')
for f in start.glob('**/*'):
    ren(f)
```